# Аналог getFullUser для aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, python-telegram-bot

У меня есть Flask API и Бот в телеге. Через API к нему могут подключаться менеджеры, а клиенты пишут в бот. Есть ли в aiogram аналог [getFullUser](https://core.telegram.org/method/users.getFullUser)?

Как мне получить инфу о пользователе по ID, при этом не получая от него сообщений в данный момент.

Answer (score 1):

Внесу небольшую ясность в вашем вопросе....

У Телеграмма есть два API - Client API и Bot API. Client API нужен для работы Телеграмм клиентов, то есть обычные пользыватели Телеграмма как раз через него работают. Bot API - нужен для работы ботов. Соответственно есть определенные библиотеки которые работают с определеными API

Client API библиотеки (Python) - Pyrogram, telethon

Bot API библиотеки (Python) - aiogram, pytelegrambotapi, python-telegram-bot

Ваш метод getFullUser является Сlient API функционалом, его нету в Bot API, соответсвенно и aiogram'e его нету. Вам нужно работать с библиотекой Pyrogram (или же telethon, но он меленовато работает), у него есть как раз ваш метод: https://docs.pyrogram.org/telegram/functions/users/get-full-user

Удачи!