# Получение юзернейма, используя ид

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

У меня есть идентификатор пользователя(id). Нужно получить его текущее уникальное имя профиля в телеграмм(username), используя идентификатор.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/906172/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-telegram-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-username-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%8F-id

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1253034/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-getfulluser-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-aiogram У меня aiogram и в ссылке утверждается, что getFullUser там нет

Comment: Действительно, нет. Тогда requests или pyrogram, или telethon вам в помощь! + https://core.telegram.org/method/users.getFullUser